# Best practice for including plain HTML files that can have event listeners handled by a different controller

Tags: html, asp.net, .net

Using .NET Framework 4.7,
I have a MasterPage that includes a Header, Body and a Footer.
If possible I want to keep Header and Footer as just .html or cshtml - i.e., plain, no .cs controller behind it.
BUT I want to catch their events such as buttons in a main file.
Is this possible, bad practice, or how can it be done?

**Edit: More explanation**

Basically I want to mimic how include() works in PHP where I can just say *"put this file's content here"* for the header and footer into an index.html.
And for the body I really want to use ajax to dynamically load various sources into an element, but what I am unsure about is how can I take care of *btn_OnClick()* events and such from the files that are dynamically loaded if they are plain cshtml without their own controller?

(preferrably i'd want to be able to say 'use this controller instead' and just use plain cshtml files)

Comment: can you not use a partial?

Comment: @Pete Yes that's probably what I'm trying to find. But how can I handle events from that in another controller if I wanted the partial view to be plain html?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you put you header and footer (which are shared across Views) in a _Layout.cshtml file.

You can also put your header and footer in separate .cshtml files (there is really no purpose for using .html in this case AFAIK) which are typically called "Partial Views" and by standard start with an underscore (much like _Layout.cshtml) and then you can render them in you layout file with `@Html.Partial("_PartialName")`.

Just be aware that if you don't put your partials in the right folder (which would be \Views\Shared or something similar) you can't call them just with their name like I did in the example but you'll have to provide the path and extension also.

Hope this helps you. Anyway it would be better if you explained more of what your plan is.

Comment: I tried using @Html.Partial(..) but the namespace was not recognized due to the project's configuration I think. Not properly set up for MVC. (inherited project at workplace). I checked that it's updated, in references, in web.config, in the end I gave up on that particular approach and have been using asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID instead. Thanks for the tip that I can put them in the same file, though.

Comment: @Alx oh I just assumed you were using MVC